# Estrutura de Dados / Lista C#

Tags: c#

O problema é:

Faça uma função para remover os n primeiros elementos de uma lista de inteiros. A função deve retornar se a operação foi possível ou não (true: foi possível, false: não foi possível).

Abaixo segue a Lista e ao NoLista

```
 public class Lista
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Referência do primeiro nó (elemento) da lista
        /// </summary>
        public NoLista InicioLista { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Construtora da classe lista
        /// </summary>
        public Lista()
        {
            InicioLista = null;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Remove um valor da lista
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="valor">Valor a ser removido</param>
        /// <returns>true se encontrar e false se não encontrar</returns>
        public bool Remove(int valor)
        {
            bool valorRetorno = false;

            NoLista auxiliar = InicioLista;

            //int i;
            //int n = valor;

            //for (i = 0 ; i < n ; i++) {

                // Verificar se a lista está vazia
                if (auxiliar != null) {

                    // Percorrer  lista (navegar) até achar o nó com o valor desejado
                    while ((auxiliar != null) && (auxiliar.informacao != valor)) {

                        // Passa para o próximo elemento da lista
                        auxiliar = auxiliar.proximo;
                    }

                    // So atualizar a lista se o valor foi encontrado
                    if (auxiliar.informacao == valor) {
                        // Verificar se existe um proximo elemento na lista
                        if (auxiliar.proximo != null) {
                            // Remover a referencia do nó anterior
                            (auxiliar.proximo).anterior = null;
                        }

                        // Verificar se é o primeiro da lista
                        if (InicioLista.informacao == valor) {
                            InicioLista = InicioLista.proximo;
                        }
                        else {
                            // Verificar se existe um proximo elemento na lista
                            if (auxiliar.proximo != null) {
                                (auxiliar.proximo).anterior = auxiliar.anterior;
                            }

                            // Fazer o anterior do auxiliar apontar para o proximo do auxiliar
                            (auxiliar.anterior).proximo = auxiliar.proximo;
                        }
                    }
                }

            //}
            return valorRetorno;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Adiona um novo valor na lista
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="valor">Valor a ser adicionado</param>

        public void Add(int valor)
        {
            NoLista novoNo = new NoLista();
            novoNo.informacao = valor;

            // Verificar se é o primeiro da lista
            if (InicioLista == null)
            {
                InicioLista = novoNo;
            }
            else
            {
                NoLista auxiliar = InicioLista;

                while (auxiliar.proximo != null)
                {
                    auxiliar = auxiliar.proximo;
                }

                auxiliar.proximo = novoNo;
                novoNo.anterior = auxiliar;
            }
        }

        public Lista Concatenar (Lista l1, Lista l2) {
            var novaLista = new Lista ( );
            Add1 (novaLista, l1);
            Add1 (novaLista, l2);
            return novaLista;
        }

        private static void Add1 (Lista nova, Lista velha) {
            NoLista p = velha.InicioLista;
            nova.Add (p.informacao);

            while (p.proximo != null) {
                p = p.proximo;
                nova.Add (p.informacao);
            }
        }

        public void Imprime()
        {
            NoLista auxiliar = InicioLista;
            Console.WriteLine("Imprimindo a lista");

            // Percorrer a lista até o fim
            while (auxiliar != null)
            {
                // Imprimir o valor
                Console.WriteLine(auxiliar.informacao);

                // Navegar para o próximo nó
                 auxiliar = auxiliar.proximo;
            }
        }
    }




public class NoLista
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Aramazena a informação
        /// </summary>
        public int informacao { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Referência para o próximo nó (elemento) na lista
        /// </summary>
        public NoLista proximo { get; set; }


        /// <summary>
        /// Referência para o nó (elemento) anterior na lista
        /// </summary>
        public NoLista anterior { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Construtora da classe NoLista
        /// </summary>
        public NoLista()
        {
            informacao = -1;
            proximo = null;
            anterior = null;
        }


    }
```

Comment: Qual é sua dúvida?

Comment: Criar a função Remove para remover o tanto de posições o usuário desejar.

Comment: poderia me ajudar @bigown

Comment: Você não está criando uma lista de verdade, para fazer isso, use: `List<int> lista = new List<int>();`

Comment: E onde está o código para esse remover dos N primeiros elementos ? Apenas vejo o código do remover normal, com base no valor do nó.

Comment: Tem que ser uma lista ligada?

Comment: @Isac, então quero saber como faço com base na posição de nó, poderia me orientar?

Comment: @bigown Sim, tem q ser

Comment: @tgcode No titulo de sua pergunta você pede uma coisa, no corpo outra e aqui nos comentários outra diferente. Vejo essa pergunta como não clara, recomendo que a edite.

Comment: @Francisco, a pergunta é para criar uma função para remover n posições de uma lista, logo pra criar a função precisa ter acesso a lista e ao nó.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para a função que precisa basta fazer um `for` sobre a quantidade de elementos a remover e ir modificando o inicio da lista para o elemento que está exatamente a seguir. Para além disso é necessário também ajustar a referência para o anterior, para que a lista continue a ficar correta.

Ficaria então assim:

```
/// <summary>
/// Remove os N primeiros elementos da lista
/// </summary>
/// <param name="quantidade">Quantidade de elementos a remover</param>
/// <returns>true se conseguiu remover todos ou false caso contrario</returns>
public bool RemovePrimeiros(int quantidade)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < quantidade; ++i)
    {
        if (InicioLista == null) return false; //se já não tem mais a remover devolve false

        InicioLista = InicioLista.proximo; //remove o primeiro
        InicioLista.anterior = null; //ajusta o anterior do novo primeiro
    }

    return true; //conseguiu remover todos, devolve true
}
```

[Veja a funcionar no .Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LJ7gII)